# Python: Loop over attributes and modify them inplace

Tags: python, loops

I have a problem and I am looking for a pythonic way to solve it. I want to do something like that:

```
def ConvertData(self):
    for dataSet in [self.trainData, self.testData]:
        convertedDataSet = ... do_something(dataSet) ...
        dataSet = convertedDataSet
```

So, I want to convert all my class attributes in the same way without copying that code for each attribute. But the way I did it does not work. In the for loop above, at the end, `dataSet` is converted properly. But naturally this will not be assigned to `self.trainData`.

What is the right way to program

```
convertedDataSet = ... do_something(self.trainData) ...
self.trainData = convertedDataSet

convertedDataSet = ... do_something(self.testData) ...
self.testData = convertedDataSet
```

Thanks a lot! :)

Edit: I found a solution with `getattr` and `setattr`:

```
def ConvertData(self):
    for attr in ["trainData", "testData"]:
        convertedDataSet = ... do_something(getattr(self, attr)) ...
        setattr(self, attr, convertedDataSet)
```

But I still don't like it. Is this the best way to do it or are there better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You question has nothing to do with `attr`, only related to the `list`. For example:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
for number in numbers:
    number = 2 * number
```

Obviously, after the loop, `numbers` is still `[1, 2, 3]`.

To change the element of a list, you need to use `enumerate`:

```
def ConvertData(self):
    dataSets = [self.trainData, self.testData]
    for i, dataSet in enumerate(dataSets):
        convertedDataSet = ... do_something(dataSet) ...
        dataSets[i] = convertedDataSet
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I did try that way allready but it does not solve my problem.
This will change the list, that is true. But I do not want to change a new list `dataSets`, I want to change the attribute `self.trainData`. So i do not have `numbers = [1, 2, 3]`, I have `variables = [var1, var2, var3]`. And I want to do `variable = 2 * variable` for each variable in variables.